# python regular expression : how to remove all punctuation characters from a string but keep those between numbers?

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds, lookbehind

I am working on a Chinese NLP project. I need to remove all punctuation characters except those characters between numbers and remain only Chinese character(\u4e00-\u9fff),alphanumeric characters(0-9a-zA-Z).For example,the
hyphen in 12-34 should be kept while the equal mark after 123 should be removed.

Here is my python script.

```
import re
s = "中国，中，。》％国foo中¥国bar@中123=国％中国12-34中国"
res = re.sub(u'(?<=[^0-9])[^\u4e00-\u9fff0-9a-zA-Z]+(?=[^0-9])','',s)
print(res)
```

the expected output should be

```
中国中国foo中国bar中123国中国12-34中国
```

but the result is

```
中国中国foo中国bar中123=国中国12-34中国
```

I can't figure out why there is an extra equal sign in the output?

Comment: Not only hyphen,but also some other punctuation characters such as comma,underscore and so on.Since the input is not predictable and it's hard to enumerate all possible punctuation characters,is there a better way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex will first check `"="` against `[^\u4e00-\u9fff0-9a-zA-Z]+`. This will succeed. It will then check the lookbehind and lookahead, which must **both** fail. Ie: If one of them succeeds, the character is kept. This means your code actually keeps any non-alphanumeric, non-Chinese characters which have numbers on *any* side.

You can try the following regex:

```
u'([\u4e00-\u9fff0-9a-zA-Z]|(?<=[0-9])[^\u4e00-\u9fff0-9a-zA-Z]+(?=[0-9]))'
```

You can use it as such:

```
import re
s = "中国，中，。》％国foo中¥国bar@中123=国％中国12-34中国"
res = re.findall(u'([\u4e00-\u9fff0-9a-zA-Z]|(?<=[0-9])[^\u4e00-\u9fff0-9a-zA-Z]+(?=[0-9]))',s)
print(res.join(''))
```

Comment: So what is the regex to keep non-alphanumeric, non-Chinese characters on both side?

Comment: Only thing I'm not sure of: Should sequences of punctuation between numbers be kept? Or do you want to keep only a single punctuation character between numbers?

Comment: Yes,sequences of punctuation should also be kept.Your code works well.Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad to help. :)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest matching and *capturing* these characters in between digits (to restore them later in the output), and just match  them in other contexts.

In Python 2, it will look like

```
import re
s = u"中国，中，。》％国foo中¥国bar@中123=国％中国12-34中国"
pat_block = u'[^\u4e00-\u9fff0-9a-zA-Z]+';
pattern = u'([0-9]+{0}[0-9]+)|{0}'.format(pat_block)
res = re.sub(pattern, lambda x: x.group(1) if x.group(1) else u"" ,s)
print(res.encode("utf8")) # => 中国中国foo中国bar中123国中国12-34中国
```

See the [Python demo](http://ideone.com/8v1ufA)

If you need to preserve those symbols inside any Unicode digits, you need to replace `[0-9]` with `\d` and pass the `re.UNICODE` flag to the regex.

The regex will look like

```
([0-9]+[^\u4e00-\u9fff0-9a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+)|[^\u4e00-\u9fff0-9a-zA-Z]+
```

It will works like this:

- `([0-9]+[^\u4e00-\u9fff0-9a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+)` - Group 1 capturing

  - `[0-9]+` - 1+ digits
  - `[^\u4e00-\u9fff0-9a-zA-Z]+`  - 1+ chars other than those defined in the specified ranges
  - `[0-9]+` - 1+ digits
- `|`  - or
- `[^\u4e00-\u9fff0-9a-zA-Z]+` - 1+ chars other than those defined in the specified ranges

In Python 2.x, when a group is not matched in `re.sub`, the backreference to it is *None*, that is why a lambda expression is required to check if Group 1 matched first.

Comment: It works like a charm and your explanation is very clear.Thanks!